# No puedo usar ciertos comandos en el terminal de VSC

Tags: python, terminal

estoy practicando en VSC y al utilizar por ejemplo los programas black, mypy, get-command o otros comandos que no sean el de python {archivo} no funciona y me sale lo siguiente.

PS C:\Users\elcra\OneDrive\Documentos\Harvard\Python\Práctica 1\EtCétera> mypy .\meows_2.py
mypy : El término 'mypy' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet,
función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si
escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso,
compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1

- mypy .\meows_2.py
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mypy:String) [], Co  
  mmandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Alguien sabría decir porque?

Comment: Instalaste mypy?

Comment: Si, utilicé el comando pip install mypy. Pero solo en el terminal de VSC, no se si tambien tengo que instalarlo en algun fichero o en el cmd